# Segue not going on Table Cell click

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a problem with my TableCell Segue.

I have setup a Segue with the identifier ShowAssesment on the prototype cell to Show a navigation controller connected to a table view, but when i click a cell it just highlights it and nothing happens.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var subjects = [NSManagedObject]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return subjects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        let check = subjects[indexPath.row]

        cell!.textLabel!.text =
            check.valueForKey("name") as? String

        return cell!
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBAction func addName(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Subject", message: "Add a new Subject", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
        style: .Default,
        handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            let textField = alert.textFields!.first
            self.saveName(textField!.text!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    })


    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
    }
    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
func saveName(name: String) {

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Subjects",
        inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let check = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


    check.setValue(name, forKey: "name")


    do {
        try managedContext.save()

        subjects.append(check)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Subjects")


    do {
        let results =
        try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        subjects = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ShowAssesment") {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell((sender as? UITableViewCell)!)
        let listVC = segue.destinationViewController as? AssesmentViewController

        let subject = subjects[indexPath!.row]

        listVC?.assesments = ["Death"]
    }

}

}
```

Comment: "I have setup a Segue with the identifier ShowAssesment on the prototype cell to Show a navigation controller connected to a table view" No you haven't. If you had, the segue would happen when you tap the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have setup your segue properly and connect it to a button in cell or so but if you wan't to be on cell tap you need to implement didselectrow and perform segue from code like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowAssesment", sender: self);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you set it up correctly. You also might try something like

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowAssesment", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
    }
```